# Azure pipeline release error while making ci cd integration

Tags: azure

Path is pipeline:

```
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_monetree.pipelines-python-django
```

error while release:

```
[error]Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a\_monetree.pipelines-python-django
```

please find my yml file from below link

```
https://github.com/monetree/pipelines-python-django/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml
```

I added - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1 to the bootom of yml file. still getting same erro

Comment: what does your copy step say? did it actually copy something?